# Where do I download the manuals for games I buy on Steam?

Tags: pc, steam

I recently signed up with Steam and bought a few discounted games, but I can't find any manuals for them. I assumed they'd be installed along with the games, but I can't find any sign of them or of download links for them on Steam. Am I missing something?
(The games are Crysis, Fallout 3, Mirror's Edge and Burnout Paradise.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a thread on the Steam forums about this: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1196986

> 1. Check the steam store page. You can right-click the game, click "view store page" and then see if there is a "view the manual" link in the lower right.
> 2. If there is no manual link there, go to Google and search for the manual there.

Here are a few of the sites that show up prominently in Google:
http://www.replacementdocs.com/download.php
http://www.meekeo.com/

Comment: Thanks. Found manuals for Crysis and Burnout Paradise via right-click > Store page.

Answer (score 7):

Not a lot of games include manuals with their Steam versions. If they are available, you can open them by right-clicking the game and choosing `View Player Manual`.

I just checked, Mirror's Edge (the only game I have in your list) doesn't have a manual, only support pages.

Comment: Didn't see any 'View player manual' entries in the right-click menus but looking at the forum post mentioned by Adam N it looks like these are optional.

Comment: The website for Mirrors Edge tries to flog you a game guide for $25  but no basic user manual :¬(

Comment: Exactly, I said `if they are available` which they aren't in Mirror's Edge's case.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the Steam store page for each of the games you own. As Arda stated, Mirror's Edge does not have a manual. On the Steam store page for each game, when you scroll down, if there is a manual for the game, you will usually find it in the right hand column near the bottom. I believe you can view the manual even if you don't own the game by clicking on that link in the store page. It is worth noting that if you own the Fallout 3: GotY edition, the manual is listed on the store entry for Fallout 3 vanilla edition, but not the GotY version.

Comment: Great, got Fallout 3 manual now too.