# Where can I find the manual for a Steam install of Tropico 4?

Tags: steam, tropico-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download the manuals for games I buy on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/where-do-i-download-the-manuals-for-games-i-buy-on-steam)

I'm one of those weird people that likes to read the manual for games to see if there are features that I'm missing or don't understand.  But I haven't been able to locate the manual for Tropico 4 anywhere on my machine, nor does there seem to be a link to it from the Steam store page.  Is there any way for someone with a Steam install to read the manual?

Comment: You don't need a manual, you have us! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a "View player manual" button as you right click the game, in your steam library. And also a link to it in the game info tab, when you left click the game.

Note: as I don't have the game myself (yet). I can't give you a print screen of the game itself, but it should be in the same place.
[image]

Comment: Not a [freehand circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775), -1

Comment: @Nick T My hands are just steady ;)

Comment: I can confirm this is indeed the manual

Comment: I swear it wasn't there the last time I looked, but it is now, so I must have been doing something wrong.